# How to save pictures from a website to a local folder

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'd need to save pictures from this website in a folder:

http://www.photobirdireland.com/garden-birds.html

I've tried by using import os

```
from lxml import html
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


class ImageScraper:
    def __init__(self, url, download_path):
        self.url = url
        self.download_path = download_path

        self.session = requests.Session()

    def scrape_images(self):

        html = urlopen(url)
        bs4 = bs(html, 'html.parser')
        images = bs4.find_all('img', {})


scraper = ImageScraper(url="http://www.photobirdireland.com/garden-birds.html")
scraper.scrape_images() 

f = open('Users/Lu/Desktop/Images','wb') # folder 
f.write(img) 
f.close()
```

but I'm not getting any results or errors.

I'm pretty sure something's not working in the code.

Can you have a look at it please and tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You code is incomplete, 1st run loop on `images = bs4.find_all('img', {})`*

*Example*

```
for image in images:
    # get the img url
    img_url = image.get('src').replace('\\', '/')
    real_url = "http://www.photobirdireland.com/" + img_url

    # get the image name
    img_name = str(img_url.split('/')[-1])

    # now download the image using - import urllib.request & import os
    print("downloading {}".format(img_url))
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(real_url, os.path.join(path, img_name))
```

---

*Complete code should look the following-*

```
import os
import urllib.request
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Bs


class ImageScraper:
    def __init__(self, url, download_path):
        self.url = url
        self.download_path = download_path
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def scrape_images(self):
        path = self.download_path
        html = urlopen(self.url)
        bs4 = Bs(html, 'html.parser')
        images = bs4.find_all('img', {})

        for image in images:
            # get the img url
            img_url = image.get('src').replace('\\', '/')
            real_url = "http://www.photobirdireland.com/" + img_url
            print(real_url)
            # get the image name
            img_name = str(img_url.split('/')[-1])
            print(img_name)
            print("downloading {}".format(img_url))
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(real_url, os.path.join(path, img_name))


scraper = ImageScraper(
    url="http://www.photobirdireland.com/garden-birds.html", download_path=r"D:\Temp\Images")
scraper.scrape_images()
```

Answer (score 1):

this `html = urlopen(url)` should be `html = urlopen(self.url)`

edit: you can fetch the urls like this

```
def scrape_images(self):
       html = urlopen(selfurl)
       bs4 = bs(html, 'html.parser')

       urls = []
       for img in bs4.find_all('img'):
           urls.append(img.attrs.get("src"))

       return urls
```

and the next step would be finding out how to download them.

Comment: Hi Fede, thank you for your answer.I have tried as you suggested, but unfortunately it is still not working. It is not saving anything in the folder.

Comment: Ok my command was a fix on what you didnt get anything on "images". 
To save the picture, you first new to retrieve the `src` from each img, then download the image stored in that address and then save that image into a file.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Comment: Thank you @ Fede Calendino. I am trying to figure out how to do as I am having difficulties

Comment: do you mean something like this:  `images.append(image['src'])
         print(image['src'])`, by looping on `images`? I am getting the following error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`, in `scraper.scrape_images()`

Comment: I think there is something wrong in how I defined or I am using the `def __init__` as it is not saving anything

Comment: I think I'm missing something here, why are you expecting for ImageScraper to do all this by itself? Maybe you are looking for a library?

The only code in `ImageScraper` is what you have right now and nowhere is saving files or doing what you expect it to do.

Comment: Sorry! You are right.I have missed to include the part where I should save the images: `f = open('Users/Lu/Desktop/Images','wb') # folder
f.write(img)
f.close()`. I updated the code. But I think the problem might be due to the fact that I am not considering a file, but a folder. It would be also good to save in a csv file in a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code to download images.use `urlretrieve` to download image src value to location.

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
url='http://www.photobirdireland.com/garden-birds.html'
data=requests.get(url).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
images=['http://www.photobirdireland.com/'+ image['src'] for image in soup.find_all('img')]

for img in images:
    urlretrieve(img,os.path.basename(img))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @KunduK. This is what I was looking for. How could I store in a separate folder (from that one where I saved my code) the files? (I have never saved a file or use a path/directory before)

Comment: @LucaDiMauro : If you working on windows just like this `urlretrieve(img, "D:\KK/"+ os.path.basename(img))` or `urlretrieve(img, "Users/Lu/Desktop/Images/"+ os.path.basename(img))`