# BeautifulSoup - How to get all the values of a certain attribute

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, image, beautifulsoup

```
<div class="cont">

    <p style="text-align: center; "><img alt="" src="/web/upload/NNEditor/20200409/1_1_shop1_143320.jpg"></p>
    <p style="text-align: center; "><img alt="" src="/web/upload/NNEditor/20200409/1_1_shop1_143320.jpg"></p>
    <p style="text-align: center; "><img alt="" src="/web/upload/NNEditor/20200409/1_1_shop1_143320.jpg"></p>

</div>
```

I try to get all the src values from this HTML.

My code is:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
div = soup.find("div", {"class": "cont"})
imgs = div.find_all("img", {"src":True})
print(imgs)
```

The list returned from this code contains  tag and other attributes such as "alt". How can I extract only the values of the src attributes (e.g., '/web/upload/NNEditor/20200409/1_1_shop1_143320.jpg')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Try adding for loop, Example*

```
for img in imgs:
    print(img['src'])
```

---

*Or to make it more simple*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="cont">
    <p style="text-align: center; "><img alt="" src="/web/upload/NNEditor/20200409/1_1_shop1_143320.jpg"></p>
    <p style="text-align: center; "><img alt="" src="/web/upload/NNEditor/20200409/1_1_shop1_143320.jpg"></p>
    <p style="text-align: center; "><img alt="" src="/web/upload/NNEditor/20200409/1_1_shop1_143320.jpg"></p>

</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')
elements = soup.select('div.cont > p > img')

for element in elements:
    print(element['src'])
```

*Prints out*

```
/web/upload/NNEditor/20200409/1_1_shop1_143320.jpg
/web/upload/NNEditor/20200409/1_1_shop1_143320.jpg
/web/upload/NNEditor/20200409/1_1_shop1_143320.jpg
```

---

*if you are trying to download images, see example*

*https://stackoverflow.com/a/61531668/4539709*

Answer (score 2):

using `find_all`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
div = soup.find("div", {"class": "cont"})

print([img['src'] for img in div.find_all("img")])
```

output,

```
['/web/upload/NNEditor/20200409/1_1_shop1_143320.jpg', 
 '/web/upload/NNEditor/20200409/1_1_shop1_143320.jpg',
 '/web/upload/NNEditor/20200409/1_1_shop1_143320.jpg']
```